# How can I use Scribe with a not-yet implemented Api?

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, scribe

I want to build a little app for myself (learning purposes) for the service http://quote.fm. They provide a oAuth 2.0 Api with a Request Token and a Authorize Url.

How can i use scribe with this api? I found [this site](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/Custom-Apis) in the scribe wiki  but it only explains how to add an oAuth 1.0a api(?)

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Regards,

Chris

**edit:**

Tried to implement the api with the DefaultApi20 class but i am stuck now in the `GetRequestToken` call which results in an exception:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported operation, please use 'getAuthorizationUrl' and redirect your users there
OAuthHelper`

```
private OAuthService service;
private Token requestToken;
private String AuthUrl;

public OAuthHelper() {
    service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(QuoteFmApi.class)
            .apiKey("...")
            .apiSecret("...")
            .callback("quotefmsharetoread://authed")
            .build();
}

public void GetRequestToken() {
    requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
}

public String GetAuthUrl() {
    AuthUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
    return AuthUrl;
}
```

QuoteFmApi.class:

```
public class QuoteFmApi extends DefaultApi20 {

private static final String AUTHORIZATION_URL =
        "https://quote.fm/labs/authorize?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&scope=%s&response_type=code";

@Override
public String getAuthorizationUrl(OAuthConfig config)
{
    return String.format(AUTHORIZATION_URL, config.getApiKey(), config.getCallback(),
            config.getScope());
}

@Override
public String getAccessTokenEndpoint()
{
    return "https://quote.fm/api/oauth/token";
}

@Override
public AccessTokenExtractor getAccessTokenExtractor()
{
    return new JsonTokenExtractor();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I solved it by looking at: https://github.com/bistri/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/GoogleExample20.java

The getRequestToken call was in fact obsolete.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing support for additional OAuth 2 providers in Scribe is quite similar to the way described in the wiki.

You basically have to implement a subclass of [`DefaultApi20`](https://github.com/bistri/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api/DefaultApi20.java) like it is done for [other providers](https://github.com/bistri/scribe-java/tree/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api). You could use the [implementation for Google](https://github.com/bistri/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api/GoogleApi20.java) as a blueprint, as they probably use a similar OAuth 2 draft as Quote.

Note that I pointed you to [Thomas Bruyelle's fork of Scribe](https://github.com/bistri/scribe-java) as the [original Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) still [lacks some features](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/pull/210) required by later drafts of the OAuth 2 specs and Quote also seems to require these.

Comment: Thanks, i see a bit clearer now. I updated the first post with my source code for the following error:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported operation, please use 'getAuthorizationUrl' and redirect your users there

I also wanted to use the fork of scribe as u recommended, but i can't build a jar of this version. I don't think i need the missing features. The used oAuth api is really simple.